# disable something on the first Wednesday of every month - jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm looking for something to disable a link at 8am every first Wednesday of every month. Whether this can be done in jquery or something else. I'm a beginner at jquery so all details are helpful. Thank you

*Edit: Also to have it re-enabled the following Friday.

HERE IS WHAT I CAME UP WITH, WITH EVERYONES HELP:

```
<!-- determines first Wednesday and first Thursday of the month to echo something different than the rest of the days of the month. --> 
<?php
$firstwed = strtotime("first Wednesday, first Thursday". date("F Y"));
$now = strtotime('today'); 

if( $firstwed == $now) {
  echo "Registration is closed until Friday. Today is Wednesday or Thursday.";
  // do something
} else {
  echo "Click Here to register.Today is NOT Wednesday or Thursday;
  // do something else
}
?>
```

Comment: have you considered server side ? someone could change their clients clock as a way around this

Comment: Your asking for a jQuery solution - this means the browser executes the code - ie it uses the clients date / time settings - if you changed the server side script (PHP / JAVA etc) then you could use the time of the server and not the client

Comment: PHP would be great. How would I find out how to do this?

Comment: Using strtotime you can find the first wednesday in the month -> `strtotime("first Wednesday of January 2012")`

Comment: Ok, so how do I apply it to solve my problem? Anyone?

Comment: I have updated my answer to point you in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO you would be better off doing this in the backed

Use this to check if today is the first wednesday of the current month

```
$firstwed = strtotime("first Wednesday ". date("F Y"));
$now = strtotime('today'); 

if( $firstwed == $now) {
  echo "today is the first wednesday for the month";
  // do something
} else {
  echo "today is not the first wednesday of the month";
  // do something else
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm working on the code right now. How would I add the time of day? For example, 8am Wednesday, but all day thursday (which I believe will just be 'first thursday')

Comment: And what about bugs? Through my reading this morning, I've seen a lot of problems between PHP versions?

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better, easier and safer to consider a server side alternative. I mean serve a different response or just disable the response for a specific request whenever you need to. That's much easier and centralized on your server. Then it's up to you to decide how to notify the user he can't use the link at certain times.

Comment: I don't need to notify the user, they should know they can't register for something while an even is occurring. I just need something simple to remove the link so they can't register. How would server side work? As long as I don't have to manually do it each month that would be great.